# ¿Cómo puedo conectar firebase a mi aplicación en React - Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema al intentar conectar la bd en firebase en mi app de React-Native, Me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la app es el siguiente:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyA5Ptq_B7LOZubMXD6vE0SZE9XnuQoKC_U",
   authDomain: "react-native-project-peti.firebaseapp.com",
   projectId: "react-native-project-peti",
   storageBucket: "react-native-project-peti.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "721830075046",
   appId: "1:721830075046:web:1dafa049fe9b581768b267"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default{
   firebase,
   db,
};
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el error como texto no como imágen

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/ lee esta documentación. Y la de firebase para Android https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup ... spoiler. La forma web de importar firebase no es igual que para android o para ios.